# Is it possible to export as USD using python?

Tags: python, scripting, export

Hi Guys i would like to export an object in USD-format, using the python API.
I didn't find anything in the documentation.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

#### [`bpy.ops.wm.usd_export()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html?highlight=usd#bpy.ops.wm.usd_export) operator

Blender 2.83 adds [USD support](https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/USD) <strike>but is still in *beta* so you won't find anything in the [current API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/index.html)</strike>. However, there is a development version of the API called [master](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/) which is mostly up to date.

Highly recommend using Blenders [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html) to figure out the operator call as well as all possible arguments:

```
>>> bpy.ops.wm.usd_export(
                          filepath="", 
                          check_existing=True, 
                          filter_blender=False, 
                          filter_backup=False,
                          ....
                          )
```

Comment: updated link https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html?highlight=usd#bpy.ops.wm.usd_export